# Perl::Critic 'Code before strictures' when using Modern::Perl

Tags: perl, strict, perl-critic

I understand that it is best practice to use Modern::Perl rather than use strict and warnings.

With default options, Perl::Critic v1.121 complains about code before strict, even when 'use Modern::Perl' comes before code.

QUESTION: Is the best solution to update the perlcriticrc config like below, or is there a better way?

[Source of config below](http://probably.co.uk/perlcritic-and-modernperl.html)

cat ~/.perlcriticrc

```
[TestingAndDebugging::RequireUseStrict]
equivalent_modules = Modern::Perl

[TestingAndDebugging::RequireUseWarnings]
equivalent_modules = Modern::Perl
```

Also of note:
[Developer Discussion Here](https://github.com/Perl-Critic/Perl-Critic/issues/270)

Comment: Looks pretty obvious to me from the discussion. There's on other way as to include it there. You could turn off the warning, but that wouldn't make sense at all.

Comment: @tjd To state the obvious that you missed, example is the relevant lines, not the entire file.

Answer (score 3):

You can "use 5.014" (or higher if available) to implicitly enable "use strict" right in the first line. Perl::Critic likes this native approach much more. After that you are free to still invoke use Modern::Perl if you still feel the need.